# Match subdirectory

Tags: javascript, regex

Given a string like `https://xxxxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net/dir1/dir2/file.ext` I would like to get `dir2`

I have this regex: `/(\.net\/)([^\/]*)/`, but this only enables me to get with capture groups `dir1`

How can I modify this to match `dir2`?

I'm using a regex to replace the string in one step.

`.replace(/(\.net\/)([^\/]*)/,'$1'+'newfilename'`

So I don't want to merely extract `dir2`. I want my regex to match it. so that I can replace it.

Comment: Do you want the second directory or the last directory?

Comment: @Barmar the last directory

Comment: It seems about everybody gets you wrong here, so maybe you could provide an example of expected output to make things clearer?

Comment: Where is your edit gone? The one where you said you wanted to have a different output for a file and a directory? You have changed your request twice already and wasted the time of a few people. I find that a bit annoying.

Comment: @kuroineko sorry, I'll try to be better about that. Here, have some points

Comment: Thanks for the points, but that's not the point ;)

Comment: @kuroineko Well, I apologized and said I'd do better. Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: @Houseman No problem here. I just meant it would have been OK even without the points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/.*\/([^\/]+)\/[^\/]*$/
```

Capture group 1 will be the last directory in the path.

If you want to replace `dir2` rather than extract it, your capture groups should be everything *except* that dir:

```
str.replace(/(.*\/)[^/]+(\/[^\/]*)$/, '$1test$2');

> str = 'https://xxxxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net/dir1/dir2/file.ext'
> str.replace(/(.*\/)[^/]+(\/[^\/]*)$/, '$1test$2');
"https://xxxxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net/dir1/test/file.ext"
```

Comment: Also won't work if there is a query or fragment that contains a `/`.

Comment: When I plug this into a `replace` function, it seems to kill my entire string.

Comment: There was no `replace` in the question when I wrote my answer. I thought you wanted to get `dir2`, not replace it.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for certain urls I'm sending. One url is I'm using the regex on is missing the `/file.ext`. Is there one regex that matches both with and without the `/file.ext`?

Comment: It always matches the last directory. If the URL is `/foo/bar/baz` then `bar` is the last directory. You want it to match `baz`? But `baz` is a filename there, not a directory -- there's no requirement that filenames have to have an extension.

Comment: You're right. I just have two different problems that require two different solutions I guess. You solved one of them, the question I actually asked. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Man, the real challenge here is to understand what is it you really want.

So, if I understand correctly:

```
input   xxxxx/a/b
output  xxxxx/a/test

input  xxxxx/a/b/file.xyz
output xxxxx/a/test/file.xyz
```

I suppose you consider '.' as an indicator of a file name.

If this is what you want, that's a way to get it :

```
function change_last_dir (str, new_dir)
{
    var split = str.split ('/');
    var pos = (split[split.length-1].indexOf ('.') < 0) ? -1 : -2;
    split.splice (pos, 1, new_dir);
    return split.join('/');
}
```

Comment: I don't just want to get the directory. I want to match it with a regex.

Comment: It would be easier if you gave us an example of input ***and*** output then. Or is it the fact that you must have regexps?

Answer (score 0):

Use [URI.js](http://medialize.github.io/URI.js/) to get the path, and then use [`.directory()`](http://medialize.github.io/URI.js/docs.html#accessors-directory) to get the directory you want.

Comment: I don't just want to get the directory. I want to match it with a regex.

Comment: @Houseman, the URI library allows you to modify the path by passing a parameter to `directory(...)`.  If you really want a regex to deal with a URL, see Appendix B of RFC 3986.

Answer (score 0):

Easy enough with pure RegEx: `[^/]+(?=/[^/]+$)`

Escape `/` since you're using it as your delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```
var subDirs = url.split('/').slice(-2, -1);
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2UDhL/)

Comment: I don't want to just get the directory. I want to match it with a regex so I can use in `replace`